# "non-JavaScript MIME type" error in electron JS + Angular project

Tags: angular, electron, mime-types

I am trying to develop an `Electron JS + Angular JS` desktop app. I referred [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-desktop-application-with-electron-and-angular/) website.

The script which I give is

```
"start:electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron ."
```

and the main createWindow function is like

```
function createWindow () {
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});

mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true
    })
);
// Open the DevTools.
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
});
}
```

After run this using the below command

```
npm run start:electron
```

I am getting the below error in console.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Attaching the screenshot for reference.

```
 [![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

**How can I get rid of the issue?**

Ubuntu: 18.04

Node js: 10.16.0

Angular: v8

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just ran into the same issue, which, if I understand things correctly, was introduced by Angular 8.

[This blog post](https://blog.angular.io/version-8-of-angular-smaller-bundles-cli-apis-and-alignment-with-the-ecosystem-af0261112a27) has the following to say about the new Typescript configuration defined by Angular 8:

> When target is set to es2015, we generate and label two bundles.
> At runtime, the browser uses attributes on the script tag to load the right bundle.
>
> `<script type="module" src="…"> // Modern JS`
>
> `<script nomodule src="…"> // Legacy JS`

For some reason however, the "legacy" option is not being generated; combined with the fact that Electron 5 (the current version) apparently does not support ES2015 modules, this leads to the message you got.

To solve the problem, I changed the `target` setting in the `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json` back to `ES5`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ES5",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I hope the Angular/Typescript specialists out there can tell us more about this issue.